Yerushalmi — masechet recommendations?
I’m interested in delving into learning Yerushalmi. Any recommendations for a good, fun, and interesting masechet to start with?

Yerushalmi is hard. You have 2 options, either go with a masechet you know and like in Bavli to see how Yerushalmi develops, might work better for short masechtot relevant le-maase (e.g., I learned Moed Katan and Beitza for this reason). Alternatively learn masechtot you don't find in Bavli (e.g., I am learning Zeraim, start maybe with Chala, Orla, Bikurim or Peah). You will need a good commentary to make any sense of it

Alternatively, there is now a Yerushalmi daf yomi program, which might make it easier to find good online shiurim to follow

Based on what criteria do you consider a tractate good, fun and interesting?

If you want something very short ,then try Makkos
